# Javascript not showing up total value in middle of Oracle APEX Donut chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, oracle-apex, oracle-jet

I am trying use below code (found from a forum) as JavaScript initialization code in Oracle APEX Donut chart to display total value in middle. But the result showing up only the Text "Total" in middle of the chart and does not show any numerical value. Can anyone help me out in spotting the error from the below code ? I am new to Javascript and have very less knowledge about the same.

```
function( options ){ 

  var total;  
  this.pieSliceLabel = function(dataContext){

  var series_name;
       percent = Math.round(dataContext.value/dataContext.totalValue*100);
       total = Math.round(dataContext.totalValue);

    if ( dataContext.seriesData ) {
        series_name = dataContext.seriesData.name;
    } else {
        series_name = 'Other';
    }
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = Math.round(dataContext.totalValue);
    return series_name + " " + percent + "% ( " + dataContext.value + " )";
} 
// Set chart initialization options 
options.dataLabel = pieSliceLabel; 

this.centerCallback = function(dataContext){
  var pieElem = document.createElement('div');

  pieElem.innerHTML = 
  '<div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:16px;">' +
      'Total' +' '+ total +
  '</div>';

  var outerDiv = pieElem.children[0];

  var innerBounds = dataContext.innerBounds;

  // Outer bounds
  outerDiv.style.top = innerBounds.y + "px";
  outerDiv.style.left = innerBounds.x + "px";
  outerDiv.style.height = innerBounds.height + "px";
  outerDiv.style.width = innerBounds.width + "px";
  outerDiv.style.lineHeight = innerBounds.height + "px";
  return  pieElem;
}

options.pieCenter = {  
          renderer : centerCallback
}
```

return options; 
}

Answer (score 0):

if I correct understood, try to fix it, add to `centerCallback`,

```
var value = dataContext.totalValue;
pieElem.innerHTML = 
      '<div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:16px;">' +
          'Total ' + value +
      '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Upon adding above code to Centercallback, the output shows as Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
function( options ){ 
// will hold the total value, must be global variable
var total;
```

Add below statement in **this.pieSliceLabel = function(dataContext){}**

```
    percent = Math.round(dataContext.value/dataContext.totalValue*100);
    total = dataContext.totalValue; //assign to global variable
```

Update the below innerHTML code in **this.centerCallback = function(dataContext){}**

```
  //updated element
  pieElem.innerHTML = 
      '<div id="myDiv" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;font-size:16px;">' +
          'Total' + total +
      '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This worked and it is currently showing up the total. But not sure if my question/code was clear enough before. Basically I am trying to have a dynamic total.Meaning when I filter attributes, total should get updated accordingly to the selection. Is there any way to set like this ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your html code and js code?

Comment: I have included recommended additions by you in my code. Am I missing something here ?